# validate the xml data in golang

Tags: xml, go, validation

My task is to find if any tag is missing in xml data or not.
Like this is the xml data

```
<people>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>2</id>
        <age></age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>3</id>
        <name></name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>4</id>
        <address>Chandigarh</address>
    </person>
</people>
```

Name and Age tags are mandatory, they need to be there
Let's take person with id:2, here name tag is missing so need to print :"name tag missing for id:2

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

type Person struct {
    ID      int    `xml:"id"`
    Name    string `xml:"name"`
    Age     string `xml:"age"`
    Address string `xml:"address"`
}

func main() {
    xmlData := `
    <people>
        <person>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <age>30</age>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>2</id>
            <age></age>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>3</id>
            <name></name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>4</id>
            <address>Chandigarh</address>
        </person>
    </people>
    `

    var people struct {
        Persons []Person `xml:"person"`
    }

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(xmlData), &people)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    missingTags := make(map[string][]int)

    for _, person := range people.Persons {
        if person.Name == "" {
            missingTags["name"] = append(missingTags["name"], person.ID)
        }
        if person.Age == "" {
            missingTags["age"] = append(missingTags["age"], person.ID)
        }
        if person.Address == "" {
            missingTags["address"] = append(missingTags["address"], person.ID)
        }
    }

    for tagName, ids := range missingTags {
        fmt.Printf("<%s> is missing for id: %v\n", tagName, ids)
    }
}
```

I tried this but the problem I am facing is that it still prints the value if tag is present but having no data like in id:2, age tag is there but having no data inside, but this code still prints it, but I want not to print it, only needs to find missing tags

Expected output:
name  is missing for id:2 4 ,
age is missing for id:3 4

Actual Output:
age is missing for id: 2 3 4 ,
address is missing for id: 1 2 3 ,
name is missing for id: 2 3 4

Comment: can you add `expected output` and `actual output` of the program in addition to the description?

Comment: Use `*string`, see [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/p-Q2hEs5dua).

Comment: [1/2] You did not read the [package's documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshal) which is a very wrong approach to programming. (Please, when facing with a problem, always start with the docs, not with posting a question on SO.) In particular, the documentation on `Unmarshal` states: «A missing element or empty attribute value will be unmarshaled as a zero value».

Comment: [2/2] The zero value of the type `string` is an empty string, hence without special tactics, a missing "something" in the XML document which were to be unmarshaled to a variable/field of type `string` is indistinguishable from that something being present but empty. @Trock offered one approach to handle this, as the zero value of a pointer is `nil`, and the manual referred to above states that «Unmarshal maps an XML element to a pointer by setting the pointer to a freshly allocated value…», so if the thing to unmarshal was present, the pointer will be non-`nil`.

Comment: There exist other approaches at solving this. For instance, a custom type wrapping a `string` and providing its own [`UnmarshalXML`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshaler) method which somehow makes available in the resulting variable the fact the method was called meaning the item in the XML document was present. Another one if using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) using one of the [available packages](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=xpath).

Comment: Hi @Trock thanks for the help, that approach is working fine, but if we want to access the values of these tags, how can we do that

Comment: Hi @kostix thanks for the help, actually I am a beginner and I am not able to find how to use XPath package in this scenario, can you help me with that

Comment: See [pointers](https://gobyexample.com/pointers). And you need a good start with  [go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#introduction) or [go-tour](https://go.dev/tour/list).

Comment: @Trock thankyou so much for the help, can you please tell me from where can I learn about XPath package

Comment: I'm not very familiar with xpath. You can search for popular packages [here](https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=xpath&m=) as kostix said. Such as [xmlquery](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/antchfx/xmlquery#section-readme).

Comment: Ok thankyou @kostix

Comment: Please take no offence, but you currently appear to lack even the most basic knowledge of the language. I mean, completing an introductory book on Go would at least make you not ask about using pointers. At this point, I would say that your task at hand is above your present skills, and our attempts to help you are useless because you won't be able to apply them (or even fully comprehend). So please work on gaining the necessary knowledge of the language first. The Go Tour is great for a start. Then pick some easy book; [this one](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro) would be fine.

Comment: Okay thankyou so much for your help @kostix